# SDL2 1-bit surface, assign one of two colors in palette to a pixel

Tags: c++, pixel, bit, sdl-2, color-palette

in c++ SDL2 i would want to access pixels and draw on a 1-bit surface same way i do with a 8-bit surface but i'm missing something i don't see.

in 8-bit surface this works fine (the pixel take the expected color among palette->colors):

```
SDL_Surface * surface = SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceWithFormat(0, width, height, 8, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_INDEX8);
SDL_Color colors[2] = {{0, 0, 0, 255}, {255, 255, 255, 255}};
SDL_SetPaletteColors(surface->format->palette, colors, 0, 2);
Uint8* pixels = (Uint8*)surface->pixels;
    for(int i = 0; i < pixelsCount; i++){
        if(*geometrical condition*){
            pixels[i]=1;
        }else{
            pixels[i]=0;
        }
    }
```

with a 1-bit surface i get a non 0 exit because of assignment (last if):

```
SDL_Surface * surface = SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceWithFormat(0, width, height, 1, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_INDEX1MSB);
SDL_Color colors[2] = {{0, 0, 0, 255}, {255, 255, 255, 255}};
SDL_SetPaletteColors(surface->format->palette, colors, 0, 2);
Uint8* pixels = (Uint8*)surface->pixels;
    for(int i = 0; i < pixelsCount; i++){
        if(*geometrical condition*){
            pixels[i]=1;
        }else{
            pixels[i]=0;
        }
    }
```

What's the right pixel assignment in 1-bit case?

Comment: The surface is probably 1 bit per pixel, not 1 byte. You are accessing it way out of range. Time to brush up on bit manipulation.

Comment: yes, 1-bit (per pixel) surface. Thx Retired Ninja i'll fight with the bits in the byte but if you could address me in the right way it'd be appreciated!

Comment: I'd use the `pitch` in the surface to figure out how long in bytes each row is. From there it's just some match to isolate the byte and bit you need to change. Probably easiest to set them all to 0 first so you only need to toggle them to 1 if the condition is met.

Comment: much clearer with that edition genpfault, if you want to answer would be fine too!

Comment: in a 160x160 px of a 1-bitperpixel surface i get a pitch of 20 bytes/row. I have isolated each bit of these 20 bytes/row. So i have160 px/row, 20 bytes/row with access to each 160 bits/row. this done, i don't find the way to link these bits to colors in palette. Some help on this?

Comment: There's 2 colors in your palette. A bit can be 0 or 1. 0 is the first color, 1 is the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, this worked for me, maybe it is not the best solution but:

1. it works
2. it can be didactic for someone else

remind, 1-bitperpixel surface, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_INDEX1MSB.

```
//coordinates
int x, y;

//more pixels than in SCREEN_WIDTH, not used here, but useful for /*geom. cond.*/
int actualWidthPixels = surface1->pitch * CHAR_BIT;

//follow the pixel
int pixel{};

//iterate each byte
for( uint8_t* byte = pixels; byte - pixels < surface1->pitch * surface1->h; byte++)
{
    //iterate each bit in byte
    for(int bit = 0; bit < CHAR_BIT; bit++)
    {
        x = pixel % (surface1->pitch * CHAR_BIT);
        y = (byte - pixels) / surface1->pitch;//pixels = (uint8_t*)s->pixels;
    
        if (/*geometrical condition*/)
        {
            //set the bit
            *byte |= (1 << 7-bit);
        }
        pixel++;
    }
}
```

Comment: for some kind of memory stuff efficiency SDL takes multiples of 4 bytes (https://discourse.libsdl.org/t/surface-pitch/16361/2) , so for 1bpp surface it's clearer to take width multiple of 4bytes.
e.g. 500px=>500bits=>62.5bytes (no 4x)=>SDL =>64 bytes (4x)=>512bit=>512px=>12px unseen. we paint them for nothing.